# Reference in a parameters file of an ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I try to add some tags on the Windows Template with this **parameters file of an ARM template**. I've seen this post [Arm template reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57192761/how-to-reference-a-parameter-within-a-parameter-in-an-arm-template/69632502#69632502) but I cant make it work.

The return value is this [parameters('imageVersionNumber')] instead of 21.10.1802.

```
    {
      "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "parameters": {
        "imageVersionNumber": {
            "value": "21.10.1802"
        },
        "imageTemplateTags":{
            "value": {
                "imagebuilderTemplate": "win7",
                "Environment": "Dev",
                "Owner": "Someone",
                "Description": "Some description",
                "userIdentity":"enabled",
                "version": "[parameters('imageVersionNumber')]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you define "type" as string for imageVersionNumber parameter?

Comment: Define it directly on the "version" line ?

Comment: It sounds like your template isn’t correctly parsing the values passed in using the parameters file. It would be useful to see that too

Comment: @NickGraham The template have no effect here. It's within the parameters file of the template. The reference is on the same file.

Comment: @AntoineV You must define it after "value" property in the "imageVersionNumber".

Answer (score 1):

You need to define parameters like the following:

```
"parameters": {
 "imageVersionNumber": {
    "type": "string",
    "defaultValue": "21.10.1802",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Image version number"
    }     
  }
}
```

Comment: Two questions. 1: Why on the link I share on my question someone says we can do this like I wrote it. 2: With your solution I can use this variable like I wrote it in my question ?

Comment: And your solution is for the main file but me I talk about the parameters file that the main link too.

Comment: To better understand how to use parameters in a file, take a look at these two links: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/parameters#use-parameter 
and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/parameter-files